# Safari displays Google font incorrectly

Tags: fonts, safari, google-fonts

Dearest of all,

Perhaps you know why Safari does not display the special character in my text correctly and for example Chrome has no issues displaying it.

I am using a Google font which I know definitely supports the special character and as mentioned on other browsers is displayed correctly.

[Please see a screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg92q.png)

Comment: Do you have a link to a working example? That'd make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: yes, the link is http://www.dukiausiniai.lt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine here, so I suspect there's a clash with a local version you have installed. Google tries to find a local version of Marck Script or MarckScript-Regular before it tries to load a version from their own servers:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Marck Script";
    src: local("Marck Script"), local("MarckScript-Regular"), ...
}
```

Also language support is divided over two font files, indicated by Unicode ranges. Your special character "ų" should be fetched from the second font, but it looks like this never happens and a generic fallback font is being used for that character. Most likely is because it will try the local version of your font again (it has the same file name), but since that doesn't contain the ų, it will resort to the fallback font instead of fetching the proper Marck Script version from the remote server.

Delete your local version(s) of Marck Script and reload the page to check if this was indeed the problem.